# Why does wind just track the economy

Tags: energy, wind-power, oil

Whenever oil booms, wind booms too. Whenever oil production crashes wind crashes too. The US added about 5GW or 2 million barrels of oil equivalent this year of wind and 300 million barrels of oil in the Permian.

When will wind stop being 1% of oil production and crashing whenever oil goes down?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Why do you think US wind energy production follows oil production? If you compare [this chart showing US crude oil field production](https://ycharts.com/indicators/us_crude_oil_field_production) with [this chart showing US wind energy production](https://ycharts.com/indicators/us_wind_energy_production) there isn't a similar pattern.

Answer (score 5):

**It doesn't.**

Assuming you're referring to wind *capacity* additions, it most closely tracks the political winds in the U.S., in the form of the [Production Tax Credit](http://programs.dsireusa.org/system/program/detail/734) (PTC), a federal incentive program for construction of new wind capacity. The U.S. Department of Energy's [Wind Vision report](https://www.energy.gov/eere/wind/maps/wind-vision) makes this relationship clear:

> [image]

This chart ends at 2013 when the PTC was renewed for an additional two years. In 2015 it was renewed again for five years, but with a 20% per year phase-out. This means that the full impact of factors other than the PTC won't be visible until after 2020 (assuming the PTC won't be renewed again, which is likely as [other factors](https://www.greentechmedia.com/articles/read/5-factors-that-will-cushion-the-ptc-phase-us-wind) will at that point be more important for driving new investment in wind).